# Using a javasscript closure that exist in an external site

Tags: javascript, web

I want to use a javascript file that exist in another host.
the file contain a closure on it

```
//http://ExternalHost.com/somefile.js
(function(){
    //...........
    //...........
    return { x:1, y:2 };
})();
```

and I want to use the returned object of the closure.

My question is

**1) how can I get that file?**

**2) how can I use the return value of closure?**

I know we can use the returned value if the file likes below

```
//http://ExternalHost.com/somefile.js
window.returnedObject = (function(){
    //...........
    //...........
    return { x:1, y:2 };
})();
```

but the problem is: window.returnedObject is global!

Comment: If that is indeed the structure of the file, you can't, because it returns from an anonymous function, so there is nothing to capture the return value of. Can we see the file? Perhaps it's using AMD and there's more relevant code than what you've posted.

Comment: @Adam we can use the return value of closure if the code was 

    window.returnedObject = (function(){
        //...........
        //...........
        return { x:1, y:2 };
    })();

Comment: That's not using the return value. That's using a global variable that is assigned an object representing variables inside the closure. I don't see what that has to do with anything, though.

Comment: @Adam yeh you're right Adam. Really we have two sub-system that I want to use a javascript file of another sub-system. the closure define a ui-component that I want to render it to my project. but the problem is I don't want to render it a few times without any conflict. can you help me?

Comment: Your comments are still very ambiguous. I guarantee that you won't have conflicts because the JS is encapsulated entirely within a closure. It seems that your only task is to make sure that you only request the JS file once, regardless of if you have 1 or 20 components that need to be rendered. This really doesn't seem that difficult - just add a single script tag (so the script is only included once). Because of the ambiguity of your statements, however, I may be missing something.

Comment: Are you sure this file doesn't modify any existing global variables (like the pattern of a jQuery plugin, for example, which adds itself to $.fn)?

Comment: @Adam yes I'm sure. and I know this file written in a really really bad style of code

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's analyze it.

`somefile.js` resides in another domain. So, you should request it from `yourdomain.tld` and it's on `externalhost.com`. You have many options:

1. Request it via a simple HTTP Get method, which is issued by putting a `<script />` tag anywhere on your DOM. This way, browser gets the file, executes it on its arrival, and you have to way to hook into this process, unless you and external host both agree on some similar protocol like JSONP, which is of course for data, not for libraries. So, this option is not useful.
2. You use XMLHttpRequest to load the file either synchronously or asynchronously. But XMLHttpRequest is by design under strict control of [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). So, external host should let you use it via some HTTP Headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This of course is applicable to normal request too. However, when you use XMLHttpRequest, you have the chance to hook into the load of the content, and do something on it. However, in this case, browser compiles JavaScript and runs it before giving it to XMLHttpRequest (your ajax call). So, again no use.
3. Understand the true meaning and philosophy of closure in JavaScript. It's like `private` access modifier in object-oriented programming. Technically it's there to NOT ALLOW you to access it :D. This options works. But it only increases your knowledge, to not expect to use that closure.

So, I think you can't AMAIK.

Comment: JSONP can be used for libraries as well, since it's not really JSON but more like "JS expression wrapped in function call"

Comment: Yeah @Bergi, you're right. It's just that I haven't seen examples of this usage. In other words, it's not normal. But yeah, technically speaking, it's possible. Nice comment.